Why does __init__.py break namespace packaging?
This package structure works fine for namespace packaging:
├──  pkg
│  ├──  module
│  │  └──  a.py
│  └──  pyproject.toml
└──  subfolder
   ├──  pkg
   │  └──  module
   │     └──  b.py
   └──  pyproject.toml

However, when I add an __init__.py to pkg/module/ like so:
├──  pkg
│  ├──  module
│  │  ├──  __init__.py
│  │  └──  a.py

Namespace packaging imports like from pkg.module.b import something become broken:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg.module.b'

My question is:

Why is __init__.py breaking namespace packaging installs?
Is there some way to work around this, such that I can have pkg/module/__init__.py as well as working namespace package installs?


Here is pkg/pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = ["setuptools>=61"]

[project]
dependencies = []
name = "my-pkg"
version = "0.1.0"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
include = ["pkg*"]
where = [".."]

Here is subfolder/pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = ["setuptools>=61"]

[project]
dependencies = []
name = "my-pkg-extension"
version = "0.1.0"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
include = ["pkg*"]

